# Joomla 2.5 change html title from view.html.php

Tags: php, joomla2.5

How can I change in Joomla 2.5 html title tag from view.html.php file. I want to generate it Dynamicaly

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle("New title");
```